# Если Array это не Generic коллекция, значит добавление в массив интов - инта приведет к его боксингу?

Tags: c#

Смотрю на сайте майкрософта виды коллекций, вижу что Array входит в не Generic коллекции.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/collections/

Array - это вроде бы обычный массив.

Значит ли это что когда я выполняю следующий код

```
int[] array = new int[1];
array[] = 999;
```

происходит преобразование int в object, т.е. боксинг? Или все таки класс Array в шарпе это не тот массив и в оригинальном массиве все работает иначе?

Для примера если я буду пользоваться ArrayList, я знаю что все что я туда помещаю - приводится к объекту. Но неужели в обычном массиве это так же работает? Вроде как обычный массив считается самой быстрой структурой, как такое возможно?

Comment: В данном случае боксинга не будет.

Comment: Проверить можно посмотрев IL код. Там такое всегда будет видно. В VS можно это сделать, а ещё можно через отдельную программу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это хорошо, но почему? Как работают массивы без боксинга, и почему тогда на сайте майкрософта тип Array указан в не-Generic коллекциях? Это какой то другой Array?

Comment: @Cordis IL код покажет что боксинга не будет, но тогда вопрос остается - почему, и как именно работают массивы без боксинга?